# SQL Server Windows Authentication over VPN using credential manager

Tags: sql-server, vpn, windows-authentication, credential-manager

I am trying to connect to remote SQL Server using Windows Authentication over VPN.
I did some research on that and found two ways to achieve this
From [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/66014/connect-to-sql-server-with-windows-authentication-in-a-different-domain)

The first approach works fine

> runas /netonly /user:domain\username ssms.exe

But according to the second answer there it can also be achieved via windows credential manager.
But that seems not working for me.

I have set these credentials in in credentials manager

```
192.168.0.58
Domain\usermane
*****
```

And the SQL Server instance in SSMS looks like this

```
192.168.0.58\\SQL2017,32839
Windows Authentication
Domanin\username
```

But this is not working. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use server name instead of IP address, server name:port , like node3: 32839. When you connect from Management Studio, make sure you use the exact same server name as the one you entered in the credential, including the port number (only now, use a comma instead of colon if specifying the port number: server,port)